# My jsp does not work in spring-boot and netbeans

Tags: java, spring-boot, netbeans-8

I am new to spring and am facing some challenges when I type in the url "localhost:8082/login?name=overflow"

I get this  "Welcome ${name}!". And if I put in the url this  "localhost:8082/login". I get an error This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback.
Any help will be appreciated

```
Application.properties file


spring.thymeleaf.prefix=classpath:/templates/mama/
spring.thymeleaf.suffix=.jsp

logging.level.org.springframework.web=DEBUG



Controller file 


import org.springframework.stereotype.Controller;
import org.springframework.ui.ModelMap;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestMapping;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.RequestParam;
import org.springframework.web.bind.annotation.ResponseBody;

/**
 *
 * @author musa
 */
@Controller
public class LoginController {
    @RequestMapping("/login")
    public String loginMessage(@RequestParam String name,ModelMap model){
        
        model.put("name", name);
        //System.out.println("name is" + name);
            
        return "login";
    }
    
    
}


my login.jsp file 


<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en" xmlns:th="https://www.thymeleaf.org/">
    <head>
<title>First web application</title>
        </head>
<body>
    <h1> Welcome ${name}!</h1>
</body>

</html>
```

Comment: [1] Please fix your title. As it stands it has no obvious relationship to the question. [2] Also, update your post to include an actual question, and the precise error you are getting within the body. The problem to be resolved is unclear. [3] Change your tag from [boot] to [spring-boot].

Comment: Also, there are literally hundreds of questions on SO citing the error message in your title. Please review the results of a search here for _is:question "This application has no explicit mapping for /error, so you are seeing this as a fallback"_ and you may be able to answer your own question.